# what does false means while creating a batch class instance in apex

Tags: apex, batch

I've got a sample code like below

```
BatchClass Bc =New BatchClass (false); 
Database.execute(Bc,1);
```

What does the 'False' parameter in the batch class instance and '1' in Database.execute method mean?

Comment: In your org, you have a class named `BatchClass`, would you mind posting it here?

Comment: Batch class name is DealBatchUpdate

Comment: We don;t work for Salesforce, we have no access to your org, we can't see this class unless you edit the question and post the code of the class here.

Comment: This pattern is actually a *code smell* called a Boolean trap.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation of your batch class named **BatchClass**

For ex can we tell what is q,e,f,v in below line, most probably not.

```
Id batchInstanceId = Database.executeBatch(new UpdateAccountFields(q,e,f,v), 5);
```

Here we are passing **q,e,f,v** to batch class. to understand what are these variables we need to look at UpdateAccountFields class.

```
global class UpdateAccountFields implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
   global final String Query;
   global final String Entity;
   global final String Field;
   global final String Value;

   global UpdateAccountFields(String q, String e, String f, String v){
             Query=q; Entity=e; Field=f;Value=v;
   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, 
                       List<sObject> scope){
      for(Sobject s : scope){s.put(Field,Value); 
      }      update scope;
   }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){   
   }    
}
```

If we look at UpdateAccountFields class then we can say q is query ,e is entity ,f is field,v is value.

So point is read class BatchClass constrictor and you will get what is false

Ref link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

Answer (score 1):

False is a parameter in your BatchClass constructor.
1 is the size of the batches of that batch class.

As martin mentioned in the comment above, you need to show us the BatchClass to be able to provide a better explained answer.

Comment: I know, false is a parameter, i want to the the result if I pass false as parameter

Comment: We can't tell you that without seeing the constructor.  What people are saying is its not a default constructor, it is something that has been coded into your constructor, so we have no idea without actually seeing it.